# Can't load data with google CLI - ImportError: cannot import name _common

Tags: python, pycharm, gsutil

I am trying to run load data from BQ using CLI .

I am using python 3.6 with PyCharm 2019.1.3 with  gsutil (google CLI) version 4.39.

I am using this command line:
 `bq query  --use_legacy_sql=false  --replace=true  --dry_run --format=prettyjson  [MY QUERY]`

using this code: 
`subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()`

Unfortunately  I keep getting this ERROR: `ImportError: cannot import name _common`

from reading previous issues related to mine I notice that there was a bug with PyCharm 2018.2.4 version.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: The exception looks similar to a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-36425